# Does foreach prefer IEnumerable<T> or IEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#, foreach, iterator

What does foreach use if a collection or list implements both IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` on an `IEnumerator<T>` at all.

You can only `foreach` over an object that has a `GetEnumerator` method (whether or not it implements `IEnumerable`.

So to answer your question, it uses the `GetEnumerator` method from `IEnumerable<T>`.

It's simple to prove.  Just try to compile this:

```
IEnumerator<char> str = "asdf".GetEnumerator();
foreach (char c in str) { }
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that. Thought foreach accepts both or would prefer the iterator interface directly. Thx for your answer.

Comment: ... missed that point because of the pattern-based "duck typing" described below and in Eric's blog.

Answer (score 5):

[`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) has a method `GetEnumerator` -  this will be an [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx), which is what is used for iteration (using the `MoveNext` method).

Answer (score 1):

Also notice, that this is not a requirement for collection to implement IEnumerable/IEnumerator in order be used in foreach loop. Foreach uses pattern-based approach as described here [Eric Lippert blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another (more relevant) question would be: What if a type implements `IEnumerable<>` explicitly and at the same time has a regular public method `GetEnumerator()` that is suitable? Answer: Then the public method is used.

And what if the type implements *both* `IEnumerable<Foo>` *and* `IEnumerable<Bar>`? Then, if there's not a regular instance method `GetEnumerator()` (that can happen if both interfaces are implemented explicitly), a compile-time error arises.